# 64 Bit Xubuntu on Full Software Raid 0 Using Mini.Iso

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, raid, mdadm

What I am asking is doable but the thing is I forgot how to do it since the last time I did. I recently upgraded my Ram to 8Gb from 2Gb. I am using an

- Asus Maximus Extreme
- with an intel core 2 duo QX9650
- and an nvidia vga (I dont remember which one)
- and 2 1TB HDD set to RAID 0 ( I will be using 2 Identical spare HDDs for the new install, the 32 bit is still operational)

running Xubuntu 14.04 32 bit with no other OS on the Drives.

I remember using an alternate install (could have been 12.04) before gradually upgrading to 14.04

Their configuration is as follows

4 separate identical partitions for each HDD containing "/" , "/boot", "swap" and "/home" with sizes of 10 GB 500 MB 4 GB and what is left respectively.

Using the alternate install and later on boot repair (don't remember how), I created the 4 md devices with a Software RAID 0, for each pair of partitions

Since I am upgrading my RAM to 8Gb I would like to also upgrade to a 64 bit Xubutnu Install
I have been trying day and night to recreate what I did last time with no results

During my First Attempt where I initialized all md devices (including the /boot) from the mini.iso, it could not install grub to (the md2 which was created)at all resulting in a Fatal Error.

In an other instance I did not create an md device for /boot and attempted to install grub only on one (disk) partition where I would attempt using mdadm after booting into linux, only to fail miserably as it would get stuck at "update-grub" and 66%.

I am currently retrying to install grub on one of the drives (at the same time creating the identical partition on the other drive with the hope that I will be able to reinstall grub after creating an md device ). This attempt has also failed, getting stuck at "update-grub", I thought that since i was not wiping clean the /boot partitions and just using quick format (only removing the address table) the installer would get confused as it would identify two /boot partitions, again with no luck.

After my third attempt and getting tired of grub i was able to install LILO on only 1 partition without using Raid ) on it, but it takes too long to boot. I would prefer to use Grub on a RAID 0. I am not sure what to do at this time, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been going at it all wrong. The simplest way is to burn your Alternate install on the usb, run it, and when you have to partition the disk, just create one partitions for "/" and one partitions for swap. Repeat this for both disks, and you are done. Make sure to turn the Boot flag "on". The installer takes care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall the only alternate now that carries the software raid 0 option is Lubuntu. Then when you get to partitioning you have to create a partition on each drive and under the use as setting select use as raid instead of ext3. once that part is done you can finish setting up the raid by selecting the partitions and then setting the file system type. http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/software-raid-ubuntu-14-04-setup-install-configure/ (ignore the fact it is for server, process still works the same but am pretty sure you need the lubuntu alternate to get the raid options in partitioning and then just install and boot into your preferred DE)